Why is my TailwindCSS not working when I deploy on SiteGround?
I have a relatively simple web app which I've designed locally and am now trying to test on a website host (Siteground) which I already have. My app looks exactly the way I want it to when I run the app locally and check it out my browser. But when I copy all the files over to my site directory, the style is not the same.
I am currently making changes in my dev environment and then pushing to git, then remoting into the SiteGround server via SSH and pulling the changes. I am developing in VS Code in Windows and the server is Linux.
Here is my tailwind.config.js file:
        /** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */

        const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')
        module.exports = {
          content: [
            "./templates/**/*.{html,js}", // Look for HTML files in templates
            "./static/**/*.{html,js}",      // Look for JS files in static
          ],
          theme: {
            extend: {
              fontFamily: {
                sans: ['InterVariable', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
              },
            },
          },
          plugins: [
            require('@tailwindcss/forms'),
          ],
        }

Here is my package.json file:
        {
          "devDependencies": {
            "tailwindcss": "^3.4.13"
          },
          "scripts": {
            "build": "npx tailwindcss -i ./static/css/tailwind.css -o ./static/css/output.css --watch"
          },
          "dependencies": {
            "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.9"
          }
        }

The directory structure looks like this:
www/\[website name\]/public_html/\[git repo name\]/all the files (app.py, tailwind.config.js, /static/css/output.css)
I've confirmed that I build the code before I push to github and then via SSH I pull the repo into the SiteGround server.
I've copied the folder structure of the SiteGround server in my dev environment and tried changing the paths on the build script and in tailwind.config.js, but that breaks my dev environment.
I'm not sure what else I'm missing that would allow me to "deploy" this app, unless it simply doesn't work on SiteGround servers?

My first thought is about the output.css : is this output on your SiteGround server ? If you compile on your SiteGround server, is it using the same npm/node version than your dev env ? What happened when you simply replace the output.css of your server by the on one your dev env which is working ?
